# Formatting string in raw format - removing quotations

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to post tweets using *tweepy* module, I already got everything working.

The only thing is I need to change the formatting of the text which I am posting.

Below is method which I am using to post tweets.

```
def update_tweet(twitter_text, twitter_handle):
    if api.update_status("{} {}".format(twitter_text, twitter_handle)):
        print("Posted for: {}".format(twitter_handle))
```

Where `twitter_text = "Hey"` and `twitter_handle` is an iterator on a list like:

```
["@user1", "@user2", "@user3"]
```

It posts as:

```
Hey "@user1"
Hey "@user2"
Hey "@user3"
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Hey @user1
Hey @user2
Hey @user3
```

How do I remove the *quotation marks from the twitter handle strings while posting* ?

Comment: So the strings in the handle list do not contain escaped quotes? Do the quotes show up when you do `"{} {}".format(twitter_text, twitter_handle)`?

Comment: Are you answering yes to the first question or the second?

Comment: @Mark quotes show up when I try to print in command line.

Comment: Maybe try slicing the string with `[1:-1]`? It isn't quite clear to me what `twitter_handle` is. Your function doesn't make sense to me unless it is a single string.

Comment: @Mark `twitter_handle` is the iterator through the list given in the question. I am iterating through it and passing to the function.

Comment: That's what I figured - something like [this](https://repl.it/MKcD)? Obviously not exactly cause that demo doesn't print the quotes.

Comment: @Mark I got your point, the quotations seems to coming from some source, thanks for helping.